# iOS Safari Jumping down page when click event in iFrame

Tags: javascript, ios, iframe, vue.js, vuejs2

So I have a video inside a iFrame (using Video.js if that helps) and the iFrame also uses Vue.js.

When you click on the buttons in the iFrame it jumps down the page. For an example load http://bestof.interactr.io and try to play the January video you will notice it jump down the page.

Interestingly on the February video there is a problem with the iFrame height (an unrelated bug) but when you scroll inside the iFrame and then click a button it no longer jumps.

Anyone have any ideas? iFrames are such a nightmare on iOS, counting down the days until we have ShadowDOM support!

Comment: Looks very similar https://stackoverflow.com/q/44954374/1300562