# iOS Safari scrolls down when interacting with video.js player

Tags: ios, css, safari, video.js, bug-reporting

Safari on iOS (10.3) jumping (scrolls down) when closing video.js player popup menu by clicking on menu button the second time.

How to reproduce:

1. https://codepen.io/mkhazov/full/PjBJvb/. Open this pen in Safari on 
   iPhone or xcode simulator.
2. Scroll down-up
3. Click on quality selection button
4. Click it again.

recorded video: http://www.screencast.com/t/IPkjEo2dxW7

It's definitely mobile Safari bug (there's no js code responsible for scroll), but I can't find the suitable workaround.

This can be fixed by following CSS as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35675094/1300562):

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

but it breaks other things (e.g. `window.scrollY / $(window).scrollTop()`) so I can't use it.

Any ideas/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: According to caniuse.com, http://caniuse.com/#search=scroll, ios safari has only partial scroll support anyway - snap points and scrollintoView are only partially supported with the webkit prefix - so the workaround outlined in your question may be as good as you'll get for the time being :(

Comment: Welcome to the world of iOS and Safari web bugs.  Or features, depending on what Apple decides to call it.